# CS:GO workshop awp skin scrambles

Tags: textures, modding

I was starting make my awp skin, but I was wondering that my skin at CS:GO looks bit different than on photoshop. So I came here for help. I will show just a test skin (fully red).

First I was save my skin with photoshop to .tga format (32 bits/pixel).
[image]
Then importing to VTF editor, but not changing any of these settings, they are default.
[image]
After that I checked only "No Level Of Detail", "No Mipmap" and "SRGB".
[image]

Opening CS:GO and workshop, awp is not fully red, there is some scrambles.
[image]

I hope for solution. :)

Comment: I don't think this question is suited for this website. It is not about game development and it is way too localized

Comment: Mod questions are allowed, though they typically don't do well.

Comment: This question was from [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222780/csgo-workshop-awp-skin-scrambles).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you have some other texture layer that's adding "wear and tear" to your model (for example the corners of the ammo cartridge). You should poke around for decals or other layers being applied to the model.

I'd be particularly interested in the slider at the bottom:

[image]